# Regular expression not matching specialist unicode characters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to match unicode regular expression but somehow the \p{L} wont work.

```
<script>
    var input="teëst";
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z-. \pL]{2,32}$/;
    var is_valid=input.match(re);
    if(is_valid){
        document.write('Regularexpression valid');
    } else {
        document.write('Regularexpression invalid');
    }
</script>
```

Plnkr.co:

https://plnkr.co/edit/3PCMxqCnwsyrueYQbB8q?p=preview

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/989121

Workaround:

```
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z- \u00c0-\u017e]{2,32}$/;
```

Comment: It's not you, it's ECMA that does it wrong ;) Js regexes don't support unicode properties.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/989121 and  http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block

Comment: My google search on javascript online regular expression check brought me to https://regex101.com/ and this validated my regexp so I thought I was doing something wrong.

I would expect such a problem in 1984 but not in 2016. However; Thanks @georg for taking the time to make me aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

My google search on javascript online regular expression check brought me to regex101.com and this validated my regexp so during the creation of this question I thought I was doing something wrong elsewhere in the code. Points out unicode is not supported yet.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/989121

Workaround:

```
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z- \u00c0-\u017e]{2,32}$/;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
var re = /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F-. \pL]{2,32}$/;
```

It uses unicode matching, [See here](http://unicode-table.com/en/)

Answer (score -1):

Try with this regular expression:

```
var re = /[^\x00-\x7F]+/;
```